# Hide div Fields on HTML output if the local storage is empty

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a problem and don't know what to do. If I save something to the local storage, the storage shows up fine. But nevertheless if the local storage is empty, the empty fields are showing up on my HTML page. What can I do to hide these fields if the local storage is empty? Please can anyone help me? Sorry my knowledge in this case is not that good.

[image]

The data is stored with value key. This works so far, but I want hide the empty value key fields on my HTML page. They only should show up, if any data is stored.

Now, my try to hide the empty Fields (length, key, getItem and so on), but it doesn't work:

```js
function showStorage() {                
    if (localStorage.getItem('value') !== null) {
        // zeigt die Anzahl der Notizen Summe als Zahl
        document.getElementById('num_keyvalues').innerHTML = '(Number ' + localStorage.length + ')';
    } else {
        var keyValuePairs = '';
        for(var key in localStorage) {
            keyValuePairs += '<div class="notizeintrag" id="notiz" draggable="true">' + 
                '<div class="notizheader" id="header" draggable="true">' +
                key + '</div>' + '<div class="img" draggable="true">' + 
                '<img src="note-small.png" draggable="true"/>' + 
                '</div>' + '<div class="notiz">' + localStorage.getItem(key) + 
                '</div>' + '</div>';
        }
        document.getElementById('keyvalues').innerHTML = keyValuePairs;                 
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you storing your data in `localStorage`? It seems by your code that you are interested in information saved with `value` key in `localStorage` but in the else branch of your code you iterate over all keys in `localStorage`.

Comment: You may have to use `localStorage.removeItem` to get a full removal. Not just set it to blank or empty

Comment: Hi, yes the data is stored with value key. This works so far, but i want hide the empty  value key fields on my html side. They only should show up, if any data is stored. Can you please tell me, what i have to change?

Comment: My "Note Delete" Button is setup with localStorage.removeItem(nameField.value) and localStorage.removeItem(valueField.value). If i pressed the button the Note will deleted. Also localStorage.clear for all Notes works, but i still get these Fields on my HTML Site.

Comment: I just tried `localStorage.setItem('test', 'abc')` and then `localStorage.removeItem('test')` and it works as expected. Maybe you can post a bit more code. Also what browser are you using?

Comment: I have no problems with saving Data to localStorage and read them. The problem is, even if the localStorage is empty, i see the empty fields on my html page. I'm using Chrome. I added my complete Code in the first Post.

Comment: In your `for..in` loop in the `else` block, check to see if `localStorage.getItem(key)` is null. If so, don't construct the HTML. Also, in `removeItemFromStorage`, you don't need the line `localStorage.removeItem(valueField.value);` you only need to call `removeItem` with the key.

Comment: What i have to do, to don't construct the HTML if the local storage is empty? That's exactly what i'm looking for. Please can you give me a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the keys using .hasOwnProperty, the fields that you are seeing are methods and properties that come from the localStorage prototype object

```
// zeigt alle gespeicherten Key-Value-Paare an 
function showStorage() {
  var keyValuePairs = '';
  for (var key in localStorage) {
    if (! localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    keyValuePairs += '<div class="notizeintrag" id="notiz" draggable="true">' + '<div class="notizheader" id="header" draggable="true">' + key + '</div>' + '<div class="img" draggable="true">' + '<img src="note-small.png" draggable="true"/>' + '</div>' +
      '<div class="notiz">' + localStorage.getItem(key) + '</div>' + '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('keyvalues').innerHTML = keyValuePairs;
  // zeigt die Anzahl der Notizen Summe als Zahl
  document.getElementById('num_keyvalues').innerHTML = '(Number ' + localStorage.length + ')';
}
```

Also you only need to call localStorage.removeItem with the nameField and not with the valueField.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i have searched for - `localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;` Now everything works, like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

really not an elegant way to handle your problem, but you'll get the wanted behaviour

```
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
             keyValuePairs += '<div class="notizeintrag" id="notiz" draggable="true">' + '<div class="notizheader" id="header" draggable="true">' + key + '</div>' + '<div class="img" draggable="true">' + '<img src="note-small.png" draggable="true"/>' + '</div>' +
             '<div class="notiz">' + localStorage.getItem(key) + '</div>' + '</div>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Wonkledge I tried this method with the attached Code, but if i do so, i can't save or restore Data to LocalStorage anymore. But the Boxes are gone in the constructed HTML page. Thats nearly what i want. Of course only the localStorage should work. ;)

```
function showStorage() {
                var keyValuePairs = '';
                for(var key in localStorage) {
                if (localStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
                 document.getElementById('num_keyvalues').innerHTML = '(Number ' + localStorage.length + ')';
                 }
                else[{                  
                    keyValuePairs += '<div class="notizeintrag" id="notiz" draggable="true">' + '<div class="notizheader" id="header" draggable="true">' + key + '</div>' + '<div class="img" draggable="true">' + '<img src="note-small.png" draggable="true"/>' + '</div>' 
                    + '<div class="notiz">' + localStorage.getItem(key) + '</div>' + '</div>';
                }
                document.getElementById('keyvalues').innerHTML = keyValuePairs;
                // zeigt die Anzahl der Notizen Summe als Zahl
                document.getElementById('num_keyvalues').innerHTML = '(Number ' + localStorage.length + ')';
                }
            }
```